# Bernoulli-measure on sup- and subspace: "Decompose" metric entropy?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, entropy

Let $X=A^{\mathbb{Z}}$ for finite set $A$ of cardinality $\text{card}(A)=k<\infty$.

Let $\tau$ denote the topology on $X$ with basis given by the set $C$ of  cylinders 
$$
C_n(c_0,c_1,\ldots,c_m):=\{x\in X: x_n=c_0,\ldots,x_{n+m}=c_m\}
$$
and $B(\tau)$ the Borel $\sigma$-algebra with the uniform Bernoulli-measure, 
$$
\mu(C_n(c_0,\ldots,c_m)):=k^{-(m+1)},
$$
on it.

Suppose $Y\subseteq X$ is a $T$-invariant subset, i.e. $T(Y)\subseteq Y$. Consider $S:=T_{|Y}$, the restriction of $T$ on $Y$. Similarly as above, let $\tau'$ be the topology on $Y$ with basis given by the set $C'$ of the cylinders
$$
Y\cap C_n(c_0,c_1,\ldots,c_m).
$$
Let $B(\tau')$ be the Borel $\sigma$-algebra with uniform Bernoulli-measure $\lambda$ on it.

> > I have two questions concerning measure theory/ dynamics:
> >
> > **(1)** Am I right that $B(\tau')\subseteq B(\tau)$ and $\lambda=\mu_{|B(\tau')}$?
> >
> > **(2)** For the measure-theoretical entropy, do we have a statement or property telling that we can "split" it like
> >     $$
> > h_{\mu}(T)=h_{\lambda}(S)+h_{\mu_{|B(\tau')^C}}(T_{|Y^C})?
> > $$

**(1)** I think this follows by $\tau'\subseteq \tau$, hence $B(\tau')=\sigma(\tau')\subseteq\sigma(\tau)=B(\tau)$. Moreoever, both $(X,\tau)$ and $(Y,\tau')$ are separable, hence $B(\tau)=\sigma(C)$ and $B(\tau')=\sigma(C')$, meaning that the Borel $\sigma$-algebras coincide with the product $\sigma$-algebras (= cylinder $\sigma$-algebras). Moreover, $\mu=\lambda$ on $C'$ and $C'$ is invariant under intersection. By uniqueness theorem, $\mu=\lambda$ on $\sigma(C')$.

**(2)** The reason why I am asking this is because I have an example where I can argue that $h_{\lambda}(S)=0$ and for further investigation I would like to know if this implies that $h_{\mu}(T)$ can be determined by neglecting "what $S$ and $\lambda$ do".  I have no idea...

In case the splitting above is not correct, maybe there is another formula connecting $h_{\mu}(T)$ and $h_{\lambda}(S)$?

Comment: What is $T$?  The shift?  What do you mean by the uniform Bernoulli-measure on $B(\tau')$?

Comment: With the Bernoulli-measure $\lambda$ on $B(\tau')$ I mean the measure which is uniquely defined by setting $\lambda(Y\cap C_n(c_0,\ldots,c_m))=k^{-(m+1)}$ for the cylinder sets $Y\cap C_n(c_0,\ldots,c_m)$. $T\colon X\to X$ is any continuous, measure-preserving transformation, not necessarily the shift.

Comment: But that doesn't define a measure.  What if $Y\cap C_n(c_0,\ldots,c_m)$ is empty?  What is $Y\cap C_n(c_0,\ldots,c_m)=Y\cap C_n(c_0,\ldots,c_m,c_{m+1})$?

Comment: I do not understand your comment. The set $Z$ consisting of all the cylinder sets $Y\cap C_n(c_0,\ldots,c_m)$ is a basis for the induced topology on $Y$ and a generator of the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. Since $Z$ is invariant under intersections, it suffices to define $\lambda$ on these cylinder sets. - - If the intersection is empty, the measure is 0 and $(Y\cap C_n(c_0,\ldots,c_m,c_{m+1}))\subseteq (Y\cap C_n(c_0,\ldots,c_m))$.

Comment: But in your definition, $Y\cap C_n(c_0,\ldots,c_m)$ is given measure $k^{-(m+1)}$.  Likewise, $Y\cap C_n(c_0,\ldots,c_m)$ and $Y\cap C_n(c_0,\ldots,c_m,c_{m+1})$ can be equal, but you are assigning them different measures.  Or perhaps I didn't understand your definition?

Comment: As far as I see, $Y\cap C_n(c_0,\ldots,c_m)$ and $Y\cap C_n(c_0,\ldots,c_{m+1})$ cannot be the same sets since $C_n(c_0,\ldots,c_m)\nsubseteq C_n(c_0,\ldots,c_{m+1})$; the entry on position $m+1$ can be different, i.e. $x_{m+1}\neq c_{m+1}$.

Comment: But you are intersecting with $Y$.  In $Y$, the entry at position $m+1$ could be forced by $c_0,c_1,\ldots,c_m$.  For example, suppose $A=\{0,1\}$, and let $T$ be the shift.  Then, the set $Y=\{...0000..., ...1111...\}$ with only two elements is invariant.  In this example, $Y\cap C_n(0,0)=Y\cap C_n(0)=\{...0000...\}$.  You also have $Y\cap C_n(0,1)=\varnothing$.

Comment: I now see your point. Can we repair it? For example, if we assume that $Y$ is such that there always exists a different $x_{m+1}$ and set the measure to be 0 für empty intersecton, this should make $\lambda$ a measure and, moreover, $\lambda=\mu_{|B(\tau')}$?

Comment: Well, I am not sure what you want to achieve.  If you have $\mu(Y)=1$, then it would be fine.  You can define $\lambda$ by $\lambda(Y\cap A):=\mu(Y\cap A)=\mu(A)$, which is a well-defined probability measure on $Y$.

Comment: No, I do not have $\mu(Y)=1$, $Y$ is a proper subset of $X$, hence $\mu(Y)<\mu(X)=1$. I would like to have the measure on $B(\tau')$ which equals $\mu$ restricted on $B(\tau')$. At the same time I would like to have the uniform Bernoulli measure on $Y$ defined on the cylinder sets. Both seems not to be possible...

Comment: If $T$ is the shift, then the Bernoulli measure $\mu$ is ergodic.  So, the measure of $Y$ (which is invariant, and presumably measurable) is either $0$ or $1$.

Comment: What if $\mu$ is shift-ergodic and T-invariant?

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: Why does „$\mu$ is shift-ergodic (which means ergodic with respect to the shift, right?) and T-invariant“ imply that $\mu(Y)=0$ or $1$?

Comment: By definition. $\mu$ being shift-ergodic means that every shift-invariant measurable set has measure $0$ or $1$.

Comment: Ok, and I guess one can assume that measure 0 is not interesting since this means Y is the empty set?

Comment: It doesn't mean that $Y$ is empty.  It only means that $Y$ is "small".  For example, assume again that $A=\{0,1\}$.  If you let $Y$ be the set of all sequences in which no two $1$s appear next to each other (i.e., $Y:=\{y\in X: \text{for each $n$, either $y_n=0$ or $y_{n+1}=0$}\}$), then $\mu(Y)=0$.

Comment: Why not $\mu(Y)=1$? Am a bit confused.

Comment: Note that under $\mu$, the pairs $y_0y_1$, $y_2y_3$, ... are independent, and each of them has probability $1/4$ of being the forbidden pattern $11$.  It follows that with probability $1$, at least one of these pairs is $11$.  This means that $\mu(X\setminus Y)=1$.

Comment: Do you mean that X\Y contains the subset of configurations with one pair 11 and that we can write this subset as a countable union of Cylindersets $C_n(11)$ over all n?

Comment: I meant the following: Note that $Y=\bigcap_{n\in\mathbb{Z}}E_n^\mathsf{c}$ where $E_n:=\{y\in X: y_n=y_{n+1}=1\}$.  Moreover, the events $E_n$ for $n$ even are independent.  Therefore, $\mu(Y)\leq\mu\big(\bigcap_{k=0}^\infty E_{2k}^\mathsf{c}\big)=\lim_{n\to\infty}\mu\big(\bigcap_{k=0}^n E_{2k}^\mathsf{c}\big)=\lim_{n\to\infty}(3/4)^n=0$.

Comment: Okay. So let’s assume $\mu(Y)=1$. Then we can choose, as you suggested, the measure $\lambda(A)=\mu(A)$ for $A\in B(\tau)_{|Y}:=\{A\cap Y: A\in B(\tau)\}$. Am I right that then $\lambda$ is also shift-ergodic and T-invariant? I think so, because $\mu$ is.

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I think one would consider the system $(Y,B(\tau)_{|Y},\lambda,T_Y)$. Is then $\lambda$ shift-ergodic and $T_{|Y}$ invariant? I do not see this. For example concerning $T_{|Y}$-invariance, I have to show that $\lambda(T_{|Y}^{-1}(A))=\lambda(A)$ for $A\in B(\tau)_{|Y}$.